# How to define array type where every element is different but shares the same generic type with others?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

for a few days I've been working on my open-source library and I've encountered a problem that I can't resolve.
Let me show you the code:

- I have an array with functions (Transformation will be used to transform one string into another)

```
type Transformation<T> = (value: T) => T
type Pipe<T> = Transformation<T>[]
```

- I have an array with two different types, but dependent

```
type SchemeOption<Value, Api> = [Constructor<Value>, () => Field<Value, Api>]

// constructor and field types look following
type Constructor<T> = <Arg>(...args: Arg[]) => T
type Field<T, Api> = (pipe: Pipe<T>) => Api
```

As can you see, the `Constructor<Value>` and `Field<Value, Api>` should have the same type of template argument.

- I use it in cases, where I'm defining the extendScheme function to extend existing scheme.

```
type Scheme = {
  [Key in string]: SchemeOption<any, any>
}

const extendScheme = <ParentScheme extends Scheme, ResultScheme extends Scheme>(
  parent: ParentScheme,
  second: (parent: ParentScheme) => ResultScheme
) => {
  return second(parent)
}
```

but unfortunately, when the Scheme is defined with `SchemeOption<any, any>`, the `any` parameter can be different in two array elements:

```
// Should be OK
extendScheme({}, () => ({
  myCustomStringPipe: [
    String,
    () => (pipe: Pipe<string>) => ({
      // ...
    })
  ]
}))

// Should FAIL
extendScheme({}, () => ({
  myCustomStringPipe: [
    String,
    () => (pipe: Pipe<number>) => ({ // the number is changed here
      // ...
    })
  ]
}))
```

Do you guys have any ideas, on how to define `Scheme` or `extendScheme` function to accept only array with the same parameter as the generic?

I've prepared Playground for this issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-uxbfsy?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you a point in the right direction:

```
const extendScheme = <ParentScheme extends Scheme, ResultType extends Record<string, any>>(
  parent: ParentScheme,
  second: (parent: ParentScheme) => {
    [K in keyof ResultType]: [ResultType[K], () => (pipe: Pipe<ResultType[K]>) => any]
  } 
) => {
  return second(parent)
}
```

This is only a partial solution.

A valid call would look like this.

```
extendScheme({}, () => ({
  myCustomStringPipe: [
    String,
    () => (pipe: Pipe<StringConstructor>) => ({
      // ...
    })
  ]
}))
```

As you can see, you will have to put `StringConstructor` in the `Pipe` type. That is the type of `String`. The JavaScript object `String` and the TypeScript type `string` are not related at all, so without any further mapping this is as good as it gets.

You would have to put some string as the first element to get the `string` type.

```
extendScheme({}, () => ({
  myCustomStringPipe: [
    "",
    () => (pipe: Pipe<string>) => ({ // the number is changed here
      // ...
    })
  ]
}))
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgJwIYDsDOAzA9ggtkkASyxQB44A+GAXhgAoA3JAGwFcoAueAShqrlCRYABULRyVWolSYc+IiQkBtALrBB0GAGUAxgAsouKAHkICsgDUW7ADQwAghEKSYSgMIk0IBKx0gcpFZsUBR2dLzUVABihFDMACaB1lB2js5qwAD0mTA6nt6+-ggwqPEwGLEJMODQaDDMWFgA1uVYzA0A7oQoAOYasB7oBX4BlDQwpPYIPRR0AHQLSNNoXFM9qhH8-TAxcYlwqU4udE7QXKLilJsOTurbugZG4wDewDCuANJQYDDdMF4Ibo9FRcB6GExmYhkVBgOwwijAAC+6jyQxgUAAHiAoCh4mCnrRSMIljiQPjYJjsbi6uS7AAlKBoVjMEBwITorE4+J1Bl5BCJAFAuEoMAUWZvGAQEkoEDnaVk-TgmwStBQVHxLgneVyhCk8nXV7vd5KD6-FAwJrfLAYGAMpkstnQEGuO3M1lCE0qMLXE5iTgwC5QUiuh0ej4qCjXGFqd6ImDAA0S3UgVgIc2q9Va3Uy7hI9TZbR6LDMsoAI1gxg+wEpXPJdGeiO9fHohpguDAblYXiwuC03iBga4Sgl7z7gN6yqN9B9p39gdIY6BgwBhRwkeb9ZHRoLCzmW8RufeagPuayOS0RZLO3sAEkADLVzm4usNpuRFsS9ud7u9-u9QeuFuABEQGTka4QbrO5x+qQgq9Ou771jABYgAYMAoKwuDlsUhB1PoqA9FAZQGLqW7vDuCz7oeMDHtw3BAA)